# What was the largest flying insectoid pollinator?

Tags: zoology, entomology, bees

[*Megachile pluto*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Megachile_pluto) is a large resin bee whose body length may reach 38 mm and a wingspan of 63.5 mm. But that's nothing compared to the prehistoric and extinct [Meganisoptera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meganisoptera) including the [*Meganeura*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meganeura), which had 'dragonflies' whose wingspan exceeded **70 centimeters!**

There are ["recent studies"](https://www.pnas.org/content/104/32/13198) linking animal gigantism in the Paleolithic to the increased atmospheric oxygen content.

Considering the size of some prehistoric insects I can't help but wonder: how big was the world's biggest insect(oid?) flying pollinator?

Comment: Define what criteria you're using for big: wingspan, body length, mass, or ?  Also, if the Meganeura were like modern dragonflies, they were probably predators, not pollinators.

Comment: Good question. Wingspan might be a fairly good measure, or body length. With no answers so far I'll gladly settle for ANY measure of size at this point.

-- As for the huge dragonflies being predatory? I'll be in my bunker.

Comment: keep in mind flowering plants did not evolve until the Jurassic.

Comment: Meganeura is from the carboniferous 360Mya, currently the biggest non insectoid is an 8 inch hummingbird. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giant_hummingbird?wprov=sfla1

Comment: Currently the best fit is probably a 28cm butterfly, lepidoptera fossils say its the biggest known insectoid pollinator, although it seems resonable that a 50+ cm lepidoptera can have been around recently.

Comment: @aliential: I'd say the largest non-insect pollinator is probably H. sapiens.  It's a learned behavior, though.  For mass rather than wingspan, I'll offer the hawk moths, some of which are indistinguishable from hummingbirds without close examination.